# Got permission denied, for changing permission for files and folders created

Tags: dockerfile

I used 'hyperledger/fabric-couchdb:x86_64-1.0.2' image to deploy on openshift.
I got permission denied for '/opt/couchdb/etc/local.d'even though I have mapped persistance volume for above path.

To resolve this, I tried to change permission defined in 'hyperledger/fabric-couchdb:x86_64-1.0.2' by creating own docker image.

I have created Dockerfile with below content.

```
FROM hyperledger/fabric-couchdb:x86_64-1.0.2
RUN chgrp -R 0 /opt/couchdb/etc/local.d && chmod -R g=u /opt/couchdb/etc/local.d
```

But when i tried to build this image using 'docker build' command, I got below error.

```
docker build . -t deepakmule/fabric-couchdb:x86_64-1.0.2
Sending build context to Docker daemon 2.048 kB
Step 1/2 : FROM hyperledger/fabric-couchdb:x86_64-1.0.2
 ---> 3f922f54bd68
Step 2/2 : RUN chgrp -R 0 /opt/couchdb/etc/local.d && chmod -R g=u     /opt/couchdb/etc/local.d
 ---> Running in f06a386ecb01
chgrp: changing group of '/opt/couchdb/etc/local.d/local.ini': Operation not     permitted
chgrp: changing group of '/opt/couchdb/etc/local.d': Operation not permitted
The command '/bin/sh -c chgrp -R 0 /opt/couchdb/etc/local.d && chmod -R g=u     /opt/couchdb/etc/local.d' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing here a bit:

The upstream `Dockerfile` has maybe a `USER` command. So all commands after that run under this user. You can fix that by adding `USER root` before the `chgrp` command. Add another `USER` command afterwards (check the upstream `Dockerfile` which user was set).